# Why http authentication with htaccess get slow when password incorrect?

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-authentication

I don't know why but when i type a wrong password it always take alot of time to come back with authentication dialog.

but when i type a correct password it always go fast.

htaccess:

```
AuthUserFile c:/senha1
AuthName "Bem vindo"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
```

I created this 'senha1' file with htpasswd.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

That's a simple measure to slow down brute force attacks.

Correctly authenticated requests are handled instantly, while incorrect authentication attempts are delayed by a second or so -- this doesn't bother a regular user that just made a typo, but it sure does slow down attackers that want to rapidly try thousands of passwords.

Comment: thanks but i figured out that phpmyadmin http authentication is very fast even when u type a wrong password.

Comment: `htaccess` checks are handled by Apache which implements a delay on failed auth. phpmyadmin probably uses its own auth mechanism that doesn't implement such a delay.